# I run npm install command but it shows deprecate, how can i fix it?

Tags: npm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9G0To.png)
    cnpm i
    / [32/36] Installing function-bind@^1.1.1platform unsupported babel-loader@7.1.5 › webpack@3.12.0 › watchpack@1.6.0 › chokidar@2.1.8 › fsevents@^1.2.7 Package require os(darwin) not compatible with your platform(win32)
    [fsevents@^1.2.7] optional install error: Package require os(darwin) not compatible with your platform(win32)
    √ Installed 36 packages
    √ Linked 715 latest versions
    [1/3] scripts.postinstall babel-loader@7.1.5 › webpack@3.12.0 › uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@^0.4.6 run "node lib/post_install.js", root: "D:\Users\admin\Documents\电商\online-store\online-store\node_modules\_uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.
    6@uglifyjs-webpack-plugin"
    [1/3] scripts.postinstall babel-loader@7.1.5 › webpack@3.12.0 › uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@^0.4.6 finished in 218ms
    [2/3] scripts.postinstall babel-core@6.26.3 › babel-register@6.26.0 › core-js@^2.5.0 run "node postinstall || echo \"ignore\"", root: "D:\Users\admin\Documents\电商\online-store\online-store\node_modules\_core-js@2.6.10@core-js"
    Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

```
The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon:
> https://opencollective.com/core-js
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)

[2/3] scripts.postinstall babel-core@6.26.3 › babel-register@6.26.0 › core-js@^2.5.0 finished in 230ms
[3/3] scripts.install node-sass@^4.13.0 run "node scripts/install.js", root: "D:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\电商\\online-
store\\online-store\\node_modules\\_node-sass@4.13.0@node-sass"
Cached binary found at C:\Users\admin\.npminstall_tarball\node-sass\4.13.0\win32-x64-57_binding.node
[3/3] scripts.install node-sass@^4.13.0 finished in 601ms
[3/3] scripts.postinstall node-sass@^4.13.0 run "node scripts/build.js", root: "D:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\电商\\onlin
e-store\\online-store\\node_modules\\_node-sass@4.13.0@node-sass"
Binary found at D:\Users\admin\Documents\电商\online-store\online-store\node_modules\_node-sass@4.13.0@node-sass\vendor\
win32-x64-57\binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
[3/3] scripts.postinstall node-sass@^4.13.0 finished in 404ms
√ Run 3 scripts
deprecate css-loader@0.28.11 › cssnano@3.10.0 › autoprefixer@6.7.7 › browserslist@^1.7.6 Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
deprecate babel-core@6.26.3 › babel-register@6.26.0 › core-js@^2.5.0 core-js@<3.0 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
deprecate babel-loader@7.1.5 › webpack@3.12.0 › watchpack@1.6.0 › chokidar@2.1.8 › fsevents@^1.2.7 One of your dependencies needs to upgrade to fsevents v2: 1) Proper nodejs v10+ support 2) No more fetching binaries from AWS, smaller package size
Recently updated (since 2019-11-21): 9 packages (detail see file D:\Users\admin\Documents\电商\online-store\online-store
\node_modules\.recently_updates.txt)
√ All packages installed (850 packages installed from npm registry, used 8s(network 6s), speed 296.59kB/s, json 751(1.7 5MB), tarball 0B)
```

Comment: It's a warning. But the installation looks like successful.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 deprecated packages from your screenshot, browsersList, core-js, and fsevents respectively. Try to upgrade the versions of packages like babel-loader, babel-core, and css-loader to a higher version. You can google "babel-loader npm", and then you can get a proper higher version. Do not upgrade to a version which is much higher than yours to avoid more troubles. Also, the warning may not really affect the development very much.